# how to set navigation drawer to be opened from right to left OR Custom Sliding menu?

Tags: android, slidingmenu

How to using Custom Sliding menu OR how to set navigation drawer to be opened from right to left?

My Screenshot is,
[image]
Please Guide me.

Thanking you.

Comment: did you accomplish it?

Answer (score 2):

Your can use sliding menu:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

```
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
```

Comment: download it but give me error with ABS. it's library is not install.

Comment: How to Download ABS Library?

Comment: you can get all the library from this url: http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-sliding-menu-like.html